# No router instance found after migrating storybook from 6.5 to storybook 7.4

Tags: next.js, storybook

I recently migrated my Next.js app from Storybook version 6.5 to 7.4 and I'm facing issues intercepting requests with mockserviceworker.js. After upgrade, my apollo client is throwing the following exception:

```
{
    "name": "ApolloError",
    "graphQLErrors": [],
    "protocolErrors": [],
    "clientErrors": [],
    "networkError": {},
    "message": "No router instance found.\nYou should only use \"next/router\" on the client side of your app.\n"
}
```

I was previously using *storybook-addon-next-router* with *RouterContext.Provider* for routing in Storybook preview.js file. Now, I've migrated to *@storybook/nextjs*, and I'm unsure if this transition is related to the issue. Am I missing some configuration?

Before the upgrade my .storybook/main.js looked as following:

```
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  typescript: { reactDocgen: false },
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    'storybook-addon-next-router',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          // When you have splitted your css over multiple files
          // and use @import('./other-styles.css')
          importLoaders: 1,
        },
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          // When using postCSS 8
          implementation: require('postcss'),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  webpackFinal: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      timers: false,
      tty: false,
      os: false,
      http: false,
      https: false,
      zlib: false,
      util: false,
      ...config.resolve.fallback,
    };

    config.resolve.roots = [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
      'node_modules',
    ];

    config.resolve.plugins = [
      ...(config.resolve.plugins || []),
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        extensions: config.resolve.extensions,
      }),
    ];

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            implementation: require('postcss'),
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: {
                'postcss-import': {},
                tailwindcss: {},
                'postcss-extend': {},
                'postcss-nested': {},
                autoprefixer: {},
              },
              config: false,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            additionalData:
              '@import "' + path.resolve('./src/styles/resources/index') + '";',
          },
        },
      ],
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
};
```

and here is after update:

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/nextjs';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/nextjs',
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag',
  },
  // Comment out on local to serve static files
  staticDirs: [
    { from: '../public/static', to: '/static' },
    { from: '../public/fonts', to: '/fonts' },
    { from: '../public/mockServiceWorker.js', to: '/mockServiceWorker.js' },
  ],
  core: {
    disableTelemetry: true, //  Disables telemetry
  },
};
export default config;
```

preview.js

```
import * as nextImage from 'next/image';
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import { RouterContext } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router-context';

Object.defineProperty(nextImage, 'default', {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => <img {...props} />,
});


export const parameters = {
  nextRouter: {
    Provider: RouterContext.Provider,
  },
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
}
```

after

```
import type { Preview } from '@storybook/react';
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';


export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
}
```

Any idea how is the *storybook-addon-next-router* from *@storybook/nextjs* or what I'm missing?

I investigated my graphql code untill I found the exception, but I'm not sure who is causing it and how to solve it. I may missing some configuration.